# session destroy help in php

Tags: php

how we can destroy the session when we click in the close button in my browser..

Comment: Erm, just to be sure: by 'the close button in my browser' you mean: 'when closing the browser' and not some button in the HTML page itself?

Answer (score 4):

You can't destroy the session directly. The session garbage collection doesn't work like that. However if your session is using cookies you could set the cookie lifetime to 0 which translates to "destroy cookie when the browser closes". You can do this with

```
session_set_cookie_params(0)
```

The session is still there, but the client can no longer access it effectively destroying the session.

On a side note this will only work if all instances of the browser close.

Answer (score 1):

You can't in any meaningfull reliable way, that is why we invented session.gc_maxlifetime & garbage collecting.

Answer (score 0):

> unset($_SESSION)
>    - destroys all session variables.

Answer (score 0):

If they have javascript enabled, you can watch for the onUnload event and make an ajax call to a php file that unsets the session variable.

Typically the browser will delete session cookies on exit, and there is no need to do it on the server side.